# Selenium Webdriver Javascript - attach to active session

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, session

I need to run a test in a window and later run other test and use the previous window (the active window). For example I run login.js the window doesn't close and later run test.js with the active window (window that it's already login). For this I want to attach the active session to the second test.

I already view many solutions for this and it's using "attachToSession" in selenium webdriver js v4.10.0 it doesn't exits.

Comment: I investigate that Protractor can use for this purpose but Protractor is deprecated and will reach end-of-life in August 2023